# Application doesn't update my location

Tags: swift, xcode, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm trying to launch simple geolocation app, however it is building without errors, it is doesn't update my location data as it should be. I'm using swift 3, xcode 8

```
class CurrentLocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var location: CLLocation?

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tagButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func getMyLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        return
    }


    if authStatus == .denied || authStatus == .restricted {
        showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
        return
    }


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    updateLabels()



}


    //Showing Alert message if location service is disabled
    func showLocationServicesDeniedAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services Disabled", message: "Please enable location services for this app in Settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }



    //Updating Labels if Location is tutned on

    func updateLabels() {
        if let location = location {
            latitudeLabel.text = String (format: "%.8f", location.coordinate.latitude)
            longitudeLabel.text = String (format: "%.8f", location.coordinate.longitude)
            tagButton.isHidden = false
            messageLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            latitudeLabel.text = ""
            longitudeLabel.text = ""
            tagButton.isHidden = true
            messageLabel.text = "Tap 'Get My Location' to Start"
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("didFailWithError \(error)")


    }


    func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations : [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation = locations.last!
        print("didUpdateLocations \(newLocation)")

        location = newLocation
        updateLabels()
     }




}
```

I can't even catch error during debugging, because when I try to write print in console there is nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using Device or Simulator?

Comment: @JacobKing Simulator

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resides in testing location-based code on the simulator. Whilst it is possible, the simulator has **no way** of knowing your location as it doesn't have access to any GPS hardware.

However, by it's very nature it is a **Simulator** and therefore you *can* **simulate** your location. This is easy to do, just open the simulator and navigate to Debug>Location as shown in the below image.

[image]

Apple gives us a couple of built in options but they are all in the USA so I like to use a custom one. You just need to click custom and enter a coordinate. Then reinstall your app and reauth your location, and it should be working as expected. Let me know if it is not.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. However this didn't help me either. https://yadi.sk/i/uUoQn-a1zjG6W

Comment: For me it also looks strange, but I don't receive anything in debug console.

Comment: Have you included your `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist`?